# node.js - push data to client - only one client can be connected?

Tags: node.js, comet

I am trying to create a server-side solution which periodically pushes data to the client (no client-side polling) via node.js. The connection should be open permanently and whenever the server has new data, it pushes it down to the client.

Here is my simple sample script:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    sys.puts('Start sending...');

    setInterval(function(){
        res.write("<script type='text/javascript'>document.write('test<br>')</script>");
    }, 10000);
}).listen(8010);
```

This basically works, but it seems that only one client at a time can be connected.

If I open `http://127.0.0.1:8010/` with my browser I see every 10 seconds the new output written. But when I open another tab with the same url, it just loads forever. Only if I close the first tab, I get conent from the server.

What do I need to do in order to server multiple clients?

Comment: That's weird. According to this page, it should work: http://blog.nemikor.com/2010/05/21/long-polling-in-nodejs/

Comment: @thejh Hm, even if I try to return a simple response with res.end() (no comet, just simple request-response) it seems to me that clients have to wait for the previous one in order to get content from the server. Maybe it is some OS issue? I am running node.js 0.3.2 on a ubuntu vm-ware.

Comment: @Max: Are you sure about the version? Even github says that 0.3.1 is the newest one... https://github.com/ry/node

Comment: @thejh yes, 0.3.2-pre, thats the output of node -v

Comment: @Max: What does `netstat --tcp` say? Two connections? Both established or one syn_wait or so?

Comment: Seems like another bug with the timers, investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, what happens is that the Browser re-uses the same connection due to `keep-alive` and HTTP/1.1 and Node screws up.

You can see this at work in Opera11, open the page twice, it's the exact same page, using the exact same connection.

Curl and everything that doesn't set `Connection: keep-alive` works just fine, but Browsers fail to open the same page twice. Although you can open 'localhost:8010' and 'localhost:8010/foo' and it will work on both pages.

**Note:** This only affects `GET` requests, `POST` requests work just fine since there's no re-using of the connection.

I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/ry/node/issues/issue/495) on this.

Comment: Hm, is there any workaround for this? Thanks for filing the bug report on this! :-)

Comment: There is, you need to do a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request (browsers won't re-use that connection then) So iirc, you'll have to an `XMLHttpRequest` here so you can set the request type, but with plain HTTP is just fails atm.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [socket.io](http://socket.io/). It handles all the heavy lifting for you and is a really cool library.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with this!

`node.js` **is** non-blocking but at the same time handles only 1 connection at a time. What you did is put the node into a dead state, that's why you see data on the second client when you close the first.